# remote script execution produce errors

Tags: shell, ssh, remote-access

I execute groovy script remotely on Linux machine. That produce me error

```
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

My command is :

```
ssh user@11.11.11.11 '/home/lib/groovy-1.5.8/bin/groovy -cp jars/log4j.jar\:jars/commons-configuration.jar\:jars/spring.jar:\$(echo jars/c\*.jar | tr ' ' '\:') bin/CreateTable.groovy'
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to escape all those characters. Try this:

```
ssh user@11.11.11.11 '/home/lib/groovy-1.5.8/bin/groovy -cp jars/log4j.jar:jars/commons-configuration.jar:jars/spring.jar:$(echo jars/c*.jar | tr " " ":") bin/CreateTable.groovy'
```

Comment: Thanks , as I understand ' was changed to " in tr command , unfortunately same error appeared again

Comment: that wasn't the only change. You also need to remove all the backslashes too.

Comment: removed backslashes , keep only one before dollar sign , otherwise I get JAVA_HOME error, but still I get same error

Comment: you need to remove the backslash before the $ sign too.